# Send POST-Request from Angular project

Tags: angular, ssl, ssl-certificate

I would like to ask how I have to set up my Angular project if I want to use call REST-API in another Server. This Angular project was deployed on https://myvokabeln.com. In this Angular-App I would like to send POST-Request to my Linux server due to generate PDF-File

```
 public createPDFList(dataJson): Observable<Blob>{
    return this.httpClient.post<Blob>(basicUrl.serverURL + basicUrl.generatePDF, dataJson, { responseType: 'blob' as 'json'  });
  }
```

and constant

```
export const basicUrl = {
    serverURL: 'http://h2916109.stratoserver.net:8080/myvokabeln',
    generatePDF: '/api/v1/pdf/basic'
}
```

But in this way I have received :

```
was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://h2916109.stratoserver.net:8080/myvokabeln/api/v1/pdf/basic'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

BUT If i change REST-API request to **https**:

```
serverURL: 'https://h2916109.stratoserver.net:8080/myvokabeln',
```

Is there problem, thet Server use Self-signed certification and it is not validit and the request is not finished.

Please can you help me anybody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found one way how to created thrusted certification:

https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/ssl/lets-encrypt-ssl-ubuntu-with-certbot/